# Micro front ends and monoliths

Tags: micro-frontend

Im interested in talking to anybody who has migrated or started to migrate a monolith using the Micro Front End Architecture.

The monolith Im looking to migrate is a single page application based upon a in house built framework.

Which approach did you take? Iframes, WebComponents etc?

Which tools/libraries did you use to help this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much like Vishnu, we took the [single-spa](https://single-spa.js.org/) route. We've combined 2 independent applications so far.

Answer (score 1):

We just started implementing micro front-end to existing application. we started with [single spa](https://single-spa.js.org/). it is a framework for micro front-end. the advantage is each module can write in different languages (vue, react, angular, etc...).

there is an another way like creating webcomponents and include without any framework [vue-cli](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2018/05/21/vue-js-web-component/).